# При нажатии кнопки "Назад" приложение крашится

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

Есть приложение, в котором Single Activity и в нём два фрагмента. После перехода с первого на второй при нажатии кнопки назад на смартфоне, приложение крашится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Буду рад помощи)

```
// код перехода с первого экрана на второй
private fun navigateToPhotosOverviewFragment() {
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_dateOverviewFragment_to_photosOverviewFragment)
}
```

Comment: Читать сообщения об ошибках всегда полезно.

Comment: Я читал, но не смог понять, в чем проблема. Вы не могли бы помочь?

Comment: вместо скрина вставьте текст и добавьте код всех тех методов, куда указывают синие ссылки, а лучше всей активити/фрагмента

Comment: startDestination указан? И ошибка ведь говорит о том, что переходим на неизвестный для NavControl`а фрагмент?

Comment: Да, указан. Фрагмент добавлен в Navigation graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?* - конечно)) сейчас абсолютно все можно найти в интернете. Вам нужно предварительно проверять на каком фрагменте вы находитесь:

```
if (navController.currentDestination?.id == R.id.fragmentA) {
    navController.navigate(R.id.action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB)
}
```

Вот есть подобные вопросы: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060762/illegalargumentexception-navigation-destination-xxx-is-unknown-to-this-navcontr), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672735/android-architecture-navigation-how-to-navigate-to-specific-place-in-nav-graph), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325285/action-is-unknown-to-this-navcontroller), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887968/navigation-destination-name-is-unknown-to-this-navcontroller-reopening-fragment). Желательно ошибку вставлять в тело вопроса текстом а не картинкой, как вам уже говорили в комментариях, и добавлять код который приводит к этой ошибке :)

Comment: Спасибо. А в каком методе это проверять? Я ведь просто нажимаю системную кнопку назад. То есть код, который за нее отвечает не находится в приложении

Comment: Большое спасибо, разобрался))

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него